# Запуск внешней программы с заданными параметрами

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell

Есть необходимость перенести часть скриптов с PowerShell на Python.

Конкретно интересует запуск программы с дополнительными параметрами. В PowerShell это выглядит так:

```
New-Alias image-unpack 'e:\Project\Perfactory\branches\Release\UnpackJob.exe';
New-Alias Check_png 'e:\Tests\!for_autotest\Jobs\Perfactory\Offset\unpack_no_offset\check.bat';
$filepath = 'e:\Tests\!for_autotest\Jobs\Perfactory\Offset\No_offset\Perfactory.job'
$resultPath = 'e:\Tests\!for_autotest\Jobs\Perfactory\Offset\unpack_no_offset\';

image-unpack $filepath $resultPath
```

Собственно происходит запуск утилиты unpack.exe и открытие ею файла по указанному пути.

В Python-e совсем совсем зеленый. Как открывать процессы нашел, но как-то не смог связать с дополнительным набором параметров при открытии.

Также буду признателен если кто сможет подсказать, как указать открытие не определенного файла а первого найденного с заданным расширением (в данном случае *.job). Заранее всем большое спасибо.

Comment: В чём конкретно у вас проблема? Если у вас уже есть рабочий PS скрипт, то просто его целиком и запускайте как одну команду (тогда вопрос сводится: "как запустить внешнюю команду в Питоне"--если не знаете как, то задайте отдельный вопрос). Вот пример запуска PS команд, записанных прямо в исходном коде (на Питоне), если вы их не хотите в отдельный файл сохранить: [на примере получения не ascii данных](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33959798/4279) (ваш случай  вероятно проще).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

С PowerShall я не знаком, да и 3-им Python'ом не пользовался, но похоже надо воспользоваться чем-то подобным:

```
image-unpack='e:\Project\Perfactory\branches\Release\UnpackJob.exe'
filepath = 'e:\Tests\!for_autotest\Jobs\Perfactory\Offset\No_offset\Perfactory.job'
resultPath = 'e:\Tests\!for_autotest\Jobs\Perfactory\Offset\unpack_no_offset\'
subprocess.run([image-unpack, filepath, resultPath])
```

(Источник https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html)
Ну или изменить последнюю команду на

```
subprocess.run([image-unpack, filepath+' '+resultPath])
```

или даже на

```
subprocess.run(image-unpack+' '+filepath+' '+resultPath)
```

ибо я что-то не встретил понятного объяснения требований к args, а у меня стоит только Python 2.7.12 и проверить толком не могу, хотя наверно должен любой вариант работать.

И по поводу поиска файлов:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724693/find-a-file-in-python
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-to-list-all-files-of-a-directory

Comment: это неверно. Константы строк неправильно заданы и использование  subprocess API также неверно.

Comment: как ни странно, но это условие subprocess.run([image-unpack, filepath, resultPath]) сработало. Хоть до этого я также нашел эту реализацию, но почему-то не получалось нормально скомбинировать параметры запуска с командной строки. Спасибо!

Comment: @Max: не может это "сработать" -- код в ответе ведёт к SyntaxError, [пример](https://ideone.com/K3XmiE)

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы передать параметры, укажите их как отдельные элементы списка при вызове [`subprocess.check_call(cmd)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess

image_unpack  = r'e:\Project\Perfactory\branches\Release\UnpackJob.exe'
file_path = r'e:\Tests\!for_autotest\...\No_offset\Perfactory.job'
result_path = r'e:\Tests\!for_autotest\...\unpack_no_offset' + '\\'

subprocess.check_call([image_unpack, file_path, result_path])
```

Обратите внимание:

- `check_call()` выбрасывает исключение, если команда завершится с не нулевым статусом возврата. Ошибки не должны игнорироваться неявно (`import this`)
- хотя Windows примет команду и как одну строчку (это родной интерфейс), для переносимости, если нет проблем с распознаванием командной строчки у вашего приложения, следует использовать список для аргументов команды
- `image-unpack` это `image` *минус* `unpack` в Питоне. Поэтому дефис на подчёркивание изменён: `image_unpack`
- обратная косая черта задаёт специальные последовательности в константах в исходном коде в Питоне, например, `'\U0001F602' == ''== '\N{FACE WITH TEARS OF JOY}'`. Поэтому `'\UnpackJob.exe'` это синтаксическая ошибка (SyntaxError).

  Можно raw-строки использовать, чтобы `\x` означал `\x` в строке, для произвольного символа `x`: `r'\U'` или экранировать черту `'\\'`.

  Нельзя `r'\'` записать в Питоне, поэтому `'\\'` используется в конце строки.